# Populating value from an object array to multiple (pre)selected option in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, drop-down-menu

I Try to add the value of (pre)selected options into the multiple dropdowns but I get only the first value rendered.

I try to add data below into multiple select>options, but I got only first(same) value from input and quidoId on every input/quidoId value

```
stationButtons: [
  {
    "buttonId": 1,
    "quidoId": "101",
    "input": "11"
  },
  {
    "buttonId": 2,
    "quidoId": "102",
    "input": "22"
  },
  {
    "buttonId": 3,
    "quidoId": "103",
    "input": "33"
  },
  {
    "buttonId": 4,
    "quidoId": "104",
    "input": "44"
  }
]
```

[Output values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e61OC.png)

I got this issue because I got every dropdown rendered dynamically because I got values(options to choose from) from API. Here is a sample of the code where I render the quidoId(TEST 101) and input(11).

```
<tr
            v-for="(btn, index) in filteredButtonList"
            v-bind:key="btn.id"
            style="border: 1px solid #6b6b6b; font-size: 14px; width: 100%"
          >
            <td>{{ btn.buttonListName }}</td>
            <td>{{ btn.buttonListDesc }}</td>
            <td>
              <select
                @change="onQuidoIdChange($event)"
                class="form-select form-control required"
                v-bind:id="index + 1"
                style="border: 1px solid #6b6b6b"
              >
                <option
                  class="quido-id"
                  v-for="entry in selectedQuidoId"
                  :value="entry.quidoId"
                  selected
                  disabled
                  hidden
                  :key="entry.quidoId"
                >
                  {{ entry.quidoName }}
                </option>
                <option
                  v-for="quido in filteredQuidosList"
                  :value="quido.quidoId"
                  v-bind:key="quido.quidoId"
                  v-bind:id="quido.quidoId"
                >
                  {{ quido.quidoName }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input
                    @change="onInputChange($event)"
                    type="number"
                    class="input-custom"
                    :placeholder="`Input ${index + 1} `"
                    v-for="input in selectedInput"
                    :value=input.input
                    v-bind:id="index + 1"
                    v-bind:key="input.input"
                    style="font-size: 12px; border: 1px solid #6b6b6b; text-align: center"
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

SCRIPT TAG

```
<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      station: {
        line: "",
        physLine: "",
        wsType: "",
        ws: "",
        name: "",
        desc: null,
        isValid: true,
        order: "",
        stationGroupId: "",
        stationButtons: [],
      },
      editIsClicked: false,
      deleteIsClicked: false,
      selectedQuidoId: [],
      selectedStationGroupId: [],
      selectedInput: [],
    };
  },
  props: [
    "id",
    "lineNum",
    "physLine",
    "wsType",
    "ws",
    "name",
    "isValid",
    "stationGroupId",
    "stationGroupName",
    "order",
  ],
  computed: {
    filteredStations() {
      return this.$store.getters["stations/stations"];
    },
    filteredButtonList() {
      return this.$store.getters["stations/buttonListGetter"];
    },
    filteredQuidosList() {
      return this.$store.getters["stations/quidosListGetter"];
    },
    filteredStationGroups() {
      return this.$store.getters["stations/stationGroups"];
    },
    filteredStationButtons() {
      return this.$store.getters["stations/stationButtonsGetter"];
    },
  },
  methods: {
    editStation(event) {
      this.editIsClicked = !this.editIsClicked;

      let idFromClickedButton = parseInt(event.target.id);

      let idFromStationListResultsId = this.filteredStations.value.find(
        (el) => el.id === idFromClickedButton
      );

      if (idFromStationListResultsId) {
        this.station = idFromStationListResultsId;
      } else {
        alert("This ID does not exist");
      }

      let quidoFromStationListResults = idFromStationListResultsId.stationButtons;

      let quidoForEditing = quidoFromStationListResults.find((el) => el.quidoId);

      let quidoFromOriginalArr = this.filteredQuidosList.find(
        (el) => el.quidoId === quidoForEditing.quidoId
      );

      if (quidoFromOriginalArr) {
        this.selectedQuidoId.push(quidoFromOriginalArr);
      }

      let inputFromStationListResults = idFromStationListResultsId.stationButtons;

      let inputForEditing = inputFromStationListResults.find((el) => el.input);

      if (inputForEditing) {
        this.selectedInput.push(inputForEditing);
      }

      let stationGroupsIdFromStationListArr = idFromStationListResultsId.stationGroupId;

      let stationGroupIdFromStationGroupslArr = this.filteredStationGroups.find(
        (el) => el.stationGroupsId == stationGroupsIdFromStationListArr
      );

      if (stationGroupsIdFromStationListArr) {
        this.selectedStationGroupId.push(stationGroupIdFromStationGroupslArr);
      } else {
        alert("This Id does not exist!");
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I need only help with the logic behind this solution, how to assign every value to every dropdown?
If I missed some important information which can help please let me know, I will be glad to share more.

[CODE SANDBOX EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/embed/cool-bessie-vge1m8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Please send your script tag as well

Comment: @BernardBorg I added it, it may be a little bit messy, but anyways tnx for your effort.

Comment: Is this vue 2 or 3?

Comment: it is vue3, do you need any additional code?

Comment: We've no idea what any of your values are because they're all just coming from black box store getters. and the one thing we do have values for `stationButtons` isn't used in your template or script code.  the methods seen in your template code: `onQuidoIdChange`, `onInputChange` aren't in your script. most data properties in the script aren't used anywhere... there's so much here that is impossible to decipher.  maybe a better option would be to provide a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) through a github repo or sandbox link

Comment: I did not include those methods on purpose because they are irrelevant for my issue. Both methods are for sending form data. It does not matter where this all data is comming from (black box). Again, It is completely irrelevant because I want to send data that I already have (stationButtons array). I simply need to put values from statiionButtons into the dropdowns and inputs  and match every value. Anyways I tried to simulate the same issue on code sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/embed/cool-bessie-vge1m8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark